# Google Maps overlapping text

Tags: google-maps

I have a bunch of InfoBoxes representing cars, and when there are a lot of cars in one location, the text overlaps.

Is there a way to avoid this? (Maybe not using InfoBoxes.) I found something called Overlapping Marker Spiderfier ( https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier ), but I need something where this happens on-the-fly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation. What I have done is onclick of a specific vehicle, close all InfoBoxes, and just open up the relevant one.

this way, there is only 1 single infobox open at any given point in time.